# There is insufficient memory for the Java run time environment to continue with elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, runtime, environment

I am running the the image elasticsearch from docker. It shows the following error. "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException".

Comment: Are you sure that you've given enough memory to your container?

Comment: share the stack trace

Comment: This you will face when you have less RAM available for elasticsearch to run. EEither you make sure you have > 512MB for elasticsearch to run. Or you can specify the JAVA_OPTS. example ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms2g -Xmx1g.